# Epsilon neighbourhood of an injective path

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

By an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ I understand the set

$$A_\epsilon=\big\{v\in\mathbb{R}^n\ \big|\ \lVert v-w\rVert<\epsilon\mbox{ for some }w\in A\big\}$$

I'm looking for a proof or counterexample for the following statement:

> Let $\lambda:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be an injective continuous path. Then for any $\delta>0$ there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $\epsilon<\delta$ and $\overline{\mbox{im}(\lambda)_\epsilon}$ is homeomorphic to a closed ball.

Comment: $\lambda([0,1])$ is compact and so bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$. That means it's contained in a ball of some radius $r$. I'd be surprised if $\epsilon = r$ doesn't work. In fact, by injectivity, your path isn't a loop, so perhaps every $\epsilon > 0$ works.

Comment: @Mr.Chip my mistake, im actually looking for arbitrarly small neighbourhood. Updated the question.

Comment: This is very clear visually, I think... you're essentially saying an arbitrarily thin slug is homeomorphic to a ball. But not sure about a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer should be negative even for $n=2$, see the picture for an idea of a counterexample. Going from the left to the right, the path converges to a point and the lengts of gaps at the bottom of the circles converge to zero.

[image]